# how do you have a colab program redirect to a youtube link

Tags: python-3.x, google-colaboratory

i want to add a sleep mode to my chat bot by redirecting you to one of those fireplace videos but i don't know the command to open links or if its possible.

i already searched on google but didn't find much useful info on the subject.